# Scoping v5 MUI Styles

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

We have a legacy application that we're slowly migrating to React and MUI.  In order to prevent overlap in styling between the different parts of our application that haven't been converted and vice versa, we've scoped styles by using an id selector in combination with a descendant selector.   For example, our styles look like this:

Example output for our styles:

[image]

This allows us to prevent our legacy styles from affecting our newer styles and our newer styles from affecting our older styles.  Before MUI v5 was released we were able to do this using a custom JSS plugin and prepend the id selector.  However, we're trying to upgrade MUI and phase out JSS completely.  Is there a way to do this with v5 using the supported styling engines?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same usecase and stylis-plugin-extra-scope dosen't help us because it only supports Stylis 3, but MUI v5 is using Stylis 4.

So, I added the plugin of Stylis 4 like bellow.

It works for me, but I made this only for me and I am not sure if it works for you.

```js
import createCache from '@emotion/cache'
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react'

const continerId = 'myContainerId'
const container = document.getElementById('div')
const root = createRoot(container)

const cache = createCache({
  key: 'ScopedSelector',
  stylisPlugins: [
    (element) => {
      // if it is a class selector, add the selector like '#myContainerId '
      if (element.type === 'rule' && Array.isArray(element.props)) {
        element.props = element.props.map((prop) =>
          prop.startsWith('.') ? `#${containerId} ${prop}` : prop
        )
      }
    },
  ],
})

root.render(
  <CacheProvider value={cache}>
    {/* Any Your Components */}
  </CacheProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom Stylis plugin? It can be added in https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/cache#createcache and https://github.com/Andarist/stylis-plugin-extra-scope could give an idea on how to use it.